# How to add table my join tables? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My question is, inside my join of IDs, is it possible to add another column with an ID?
This is what I am trying to do:

My Index:

```cs
var orders= db.Orders.ToList();
var colers = db.Colors.ToList();
var result = (from c in orders
             join st in colers on c.ID_Orders equals st.id into table1
             select new OrderWithColorsViewModel { order =c, colers = table1.ToList() 
}).ToList();

return View(result);
```

My classes:

```cs
public partial class Orders
{
    public int ID_Orders { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Data_Registo { get; set; }
    public string Num_Encomenda { get; set; }
    public string Ref_Cliente { get; set; }
}

public partial class Colors
{
    public int ID_Orders { get; set; }
    public int ID_Line_Color { get; set; }
    public string Color{ get; set; }
}

public partial class Quantities
{
    public int ID_Orders { get; set; }
    public int ID_Line_Color { get; set; }
    public int quantity{ get; set; }
}
```

Of what I am learning right now I have this from my join:

[image: order]

and:

[image: line_color]

But what I want (I think):

[image: order_color-line]

**If i am wrong in thinking, correct me, thanks**

Comment: You can't have a property (Quantities) named the same thing as the class it is within.

Comment: sorry it was a mistake in translation, this situation is not happening

Comment: To clarify, is each class representative of a table in a database?

Comment: Yes, 3 tables, Orders, Colors and Quantities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I leave my solution here for those who need it

```
var result1 = (from o in order
               join c in coler
                  on o.ID_Programa equals c.ID_Programa into co
               group new { o, co } by o.ID_Programa into g
               from i in g
               select new { order = i.o, colors = i.co }).ToList();
var result2 = (from r1 in result1
               from c in r1.colors
               join q in quant
                 on new { orderId = c.ID_Programa, colorlineId = c.ID_Linha_Cor } equals new { orderId = q.ID_Programa, colorlineId = q.ID_Linha_Cor } into p1
               from p in p1
               join s in statu
                 on new { orderId = p.ID_Programa, colorlineId = p.ID_Linha_Cor } equals new { orderId = s.ID_Programa, colorlineId = s.ID_Linha_Cor } into q
               group new ColorsAndQuantities { coler = c, quant = p1.ToList(), status = q.ToList() } by c.ID_Programa).ToList();
var result = (from r1 in result1
              join m in fabric
                on r1.order.ID_Programa equals m.ID_Programa into t
                from t1 in t
              join r2 in result2
                 on t1.ID_Programa equals r2.Key
              select new OrdersColorsViewModel
              {
                  order = r1.order,
                  malhas = t1,
                  colers = r2.ToList()
              }).ToList();
```